# Failed to load session ''ubuntu'' after Upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, session

I upgraded from 11.04 to 12.04. After closing the computer and trying to login again, it presented me with `failed to load session "ubuntu"`.

What can I do to rectify the problem?

Comment: Do you have Compiz installed?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu recommends only upgrade to it's immediate successor release versions. i.e: 11.04 to 11.10, 11.10 to 12.04 etc.
I am not sure this will work or not, but try this.

on the login screen press Alt+Ctrl+f1 and go to tty1 and type following commands.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get update
```

After that restart your pc.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Hope this will work for you.